# How to convert Linq result to viewmodel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

while filling a combobx, I need to convert a Linq-result to a viewmodel.

Actually, I query the records and then I fill a list of the viewmodel in a loop, but that seems to be a bit strange:

```
public static IEnumerable<ComboBoxActivities> GetActivitySelectList()
    {
        using(ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {

            var result = from activity in db.Activities
                         where activity.Available
                         select new
                         {
                             ActivityId = activity.Id,
                             ActivityName = activity.ActivityName,
                             Available = activity.Available
                         };

            List<ComboBoxActivities> list = new List<ComboBoxActivities>();
            foreach(var res in result)
            {
                ComboBoxActivities listItem = new ComboBoxActivities()
                {
                    ActivityId= res.ActivityId,
                    ActivityName= res.ActivityName,
                    Available= res.Available
                };
                list.Add(listItem);
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
```

Is this really the right way?
I also tried:

```
 var result = from activity in db.Activities
                         where activity.Available
                         select new ComboBoxActivities()
                         {
                             ActivityId = activity.Id,
                             ActivityName = activity.ActivityName,
                             Available = activity.Available
                         };
```

But then my razorview crashes with the message that direct binding to a quers (DbSet, DbQuery...) is not supported.

Comment: You realize your function expects to return `IEnumerable<ComboBoxActivities>` and is actually returning `List<ComboBoxActivities>`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>` by using `ToList()`

```
public static List<ComboBoxActivities> GetActivitySelectList()
  {
    using(ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {

        var result = from activity in db.Activities
                     where activity.Available
                     select new ComboBoxActivities()
                     {
                         ActivityId = activity.Id,
                         ActivityName = activity.ActivityName,
                         Available = activity.Available
                     };

        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

As for loading a ComboBox from a table query, ComboBox has a DataSource property which you can assign the List to.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Same result. I knew toList() but it is still a result of a query. Somehow the view collides with it's model and the result of the ComboBox records.

Comment: What line does the exception happen on? how are you assigning the list to the combobox?

Comment: The exception happens at the end of the gridview-control (DevExpress), where the model is Bound. `@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()` Normally this has Nothing to do with the Combobox, because it is nested inside the grid. The easy (working) way is a ´BindList(GetActivitySelectList());´ - property of the Combobox. If I try to use the DataSource-property, it also works with the model but not with the linq result.